# Which verbiage is appropriate for a combined login/register button and why?

Tags: web-app, login, signup-signon

I'm creating a combined login/sign up form. When the user clicks the action button an ajax call is made which either:

1. Logs the user in, if the account exists.
2. Signs the user up, and then logs them in if the account does not exist.

I'm trying to figure out the ideal action word(s) for the login/sign up button. I'm wary of combining text such as "Sign In / Login" in one button and would like to keep it to ideally one or two words. I'd also rather not split the button in two.

The primary text on the page says "Find stuff you'll love," right above the login widget. I'm thinking the button verbiage can make use of this, so up until now I've used the word "Start," because whether or not you have an account you can still "start finding stuff."

**Edit:** To clarify the question, which verbiage is most appropriate for a combined login/register button and why?

[image]

Comment: maybe you can reword the question to ask something along the lines of "how can I combine login and register into one form". Rather than specifically about the wording of the button, you may get some better ideas

Comment: for example - http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45366/why-should-you-provide-a-sign-up-link-from-your-login-form?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

These words are action based words, and are also not specific to logging in or joining. Either way the user is taken to the next screen.

- Continue
- Next
- Get Started
- Let's Go
- Go

Also unless you are somehow informing the new user that this is the first step in joining this set up will most likely cause confusion due to the fact that most users will attempt to login, and will not remember ever having a password.

Comment: Why? what is the reasoning for these suggestions? Do users respond better to these than others?

Comment: You should not vote down an answer because there is no explanation, especially if you did not ask for one in your question.

Comment: People are free to downvote however they deem appropriate. I did so and left a comment explaining why. You have now added a bit more detail so I've retracted my downvote.

Comment: If an appropriate action word is chosen there should be no confusion. The login form is in the very center of the landing page surrounded by whitespace and the only action possible is to enter login information.